# Strangely encoded output with "\u0026 quot;" inside

Tags: javascript, .net, web-services

I am using a text service and I should receive output like
this

> abc
>
> "11"
>
> 12 " abcd "14" ab
>
> 15/42
>
> "15/42"

But I receive it like this

> abc\n\u0026 Quot; 11 \u0026 quot;\n12 \u0026 quot; abcd \u0026 quot;
> 14 \u0026 quot; ab\n15/42\n\u0026 Quot; 15/42 \u0026 quot;

Newline is changed with "\n"
and " is changed with "\u0026 quot"

Any ideas what type of encoding is this?

Are there any .net tools to decode this to normal state.

Of course I can replace all characters with needed, but not sure I am aware about all changed characters.

Comment: How are you receiving the text from the web service?  Please show some code as that might give a hint as to how and where the string is mangled.

Comment: It sounds like it's returning JSON, and you're not decoding it.

Comment: Try calling `JSON.parse()` on the response.

Comment: I was trying to Parse, as you said. Received exception

var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);

Ex: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: String

Answer (score 1):

`\u0026` is the Unicode representation of `&`.
Thus the `\u0026 quot;` you are getting is likely butchered HTML escaped data. (`&quot;` in HTML will result in a rendered `"`)

In theory you should be fine by just replacing those unicode chars with their ACSII representation.
(eg. http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%5Cu0026)

Comment: Up vote for noting that the string is "butchered", i.e., double encoded.

Comment: I suspect it's returning JSON and he's not calling `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: I also suspect the double conversion is the case.